# heroku - run application using foreman

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

i've created a `.env` file in my application to configure the `NODE_ENV` variable. Though, everytime i do `push` to my heroku repo, heroku toolbelt restarts my application ignoring the `.env` file, forcing me to run `foreman start` manually.

how do i configure my application to always start using foreman command?

Answer (score 1):

$nf start web

$nf start mobile

$nf start develop